# ZonedDateTime in Brazil still getting -2 instead of -3 offset

Tags: java, date, timezone, dst, zoneddatetime

I'm working in a application that uses Java 8, Maven and Spring. Since 2019, the DayLight Saving Time was abolished in Brazil.

Basically I am changing all dates in the system to save in utc and be shown in the time zone of whoever is using the application. Most users are from Brazil

To fix the time zone problem I updated the JRE and JDK to the latest versions of java 8, and so all the dates that were indicating to be in summer time, started to return to normal time. 
With that I was able to convert the dates and I have been doing this for about two weeks

The problem is that today, around lunchtime, all the conversions I've been doing have suddenly returned to indicate daylight saving time, even without updating anything at all

Example:

```
calculatedList.forEach(dto -> {
    LocalDateTime date = dto.getResultDate();

    dto.setResultDate(date.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo")).toLocalDateTime());
});
```

when I wrote this code, I made sure that the conversion took a date in utc and brought it to -3. Now this same method is converting to -2

I've been making codes like this for 2 weeks and everything has been working as it should until now. It's a very vague question, but I just can't imagine what I might have done to make the time zone go wrong. Can anyone help me understand what happened?

Comment: which JRE8 update are you using?

Comment: I update in the Control Panel of Java.

Comment: Try to add `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));` within your code and see what the output is.

Comment: output is 1.8.0_221. Surely the problem is here! But my variables are all pointed to version 1.8.0_241

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per this page: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html

Brazil no longer observes DST since:

- 13.0.1
- 11.0.5
- 8u231
- 7u241

while your Java version is `1.8.0_221` which does not include that change.

Comment: But JAVA_HOME is pointing to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241

Comment: How do you run your application?

Comment: using maven. mvn spring-boot:run

Comment: Try `java -version`.

Comment: java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)

Comment: running where java it shows: 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\java.exe

Comment: I am not sure, but there is some misconfiguration on the system. Try `mvn -version`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208215/discussion-between-vinicius-britto-and-eng-fouad).